# Grub2 does not boot dualboot windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

For the administrators: please kindly put this question into different sections if you see fit.

My laptop is Lenovo ThinkPad E555. Recently I installed Ubuntu Mint 1610, and yesterday I installed Windows 10, both out of bootable USBs. 
I have set the BIOS so that it is under UEFI with no CSM support and no secureBoot, and my hard drive is of GPT format.

Throughout the whole process, I have no problems booting Ubuntu using grub2.

After the whole process installing windows into my computer and booting into Windows (and it prompted to configure usernames and other settings), I see the windows desktop, shut off the computer immediately, turned on Ubuntu again, and tried to add in grub2 the windows entry.

After having `boot-repair` installed from ppa of "yannubuntu", I ran this program. It didn't help. In fact, I have run it multiple times, using different options, but with no luck. The last time I ran this program, I selected to upload it into a pastebin: http://paste2.org/I28GVzGm

Now I am stuck in the middle of nowhere for booting windows using grub2. I have tried to plug in the windows installer, select to repair the booting, but it couldn't help. I tried to do the following in grub, but still nothing happens:

```
setparam "Windows" {
    set root='hd0,1'
    chainloader +1
}
```

Another thing I did was that seeing grub2 uses `chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` in the last line for windows booting (added by `boot-repair`), and there are some other efi files under the same directory, I tried to change "bootmgfw.efi" into things such as "bootmgr.efi" and "bootx64.efi". Still, nothing.

Now I have run out of ideas of how to solve it. Please reply if you have some ideas, and I am more than willing to add any additional information obtainable from my computer.

Thanks for all who are trying to help me!

**Edit 1:**

I have already run `sudo update-grub`, but it didn't help.

**Edit 2:**

When I tried to boot windows 10 from grub2 menu, nothing happens: it immediately switched back to the same screen -- the grub2 menu, as if I had not touched anything. I also tried to press 'e' on the entry to enter edit mode, and press F10 to run, it showed the following:

```
    file path: ...((directory to /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi))/EndEntire
    error: unknown error
```

When booting from rEFInd suggested by Rod Smith using a flashdrive, the first entry was the only entry for windows, but when I tried to boot from it, the following lines showed up:

```
    Starting bootmgfw.efi
    Using load options ''
    Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not Found
    Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi: Not Found
    Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\MoKManager.efi - Not Found
    Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\MoKManager.efi: Not Found
```

I have tried to boot from pressing F12 (boot options) when turning on my laptop, and selected Windows there, but it also didn't do anything as if I never stroke any key.

I have converted the EFI partition to FAT32 (files backed up and returned using `zip` and `unzip`), modified /etc/fstab, and tried `boot-repair` again, and when booting from grub2, the same thing happened as I described earlier with grub2.

I also tried `dosfsck` on my EFI, but it didn't affect the result at all. Inspired by that, I tried to use the cmd on Windows Install Disk to perform both `sfc/scannow` and `chkdsk/f c:`(where "c:" points to /dev/sda6, the partition where windows was installed), but after that I still don't see anything different when trying to boot from grub2.

Answer (score 1):

The `chainloader +1` syntax in the `grub.cfg` Windows boot option you posted works on *BIOS-mode* installations; for an EFI-mode installation like yours, you must chainload to an EFI boot loader file -- normally `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` for Windows. The `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)` option from your Boot Repair output looks correct to me, although I may be missing some detail.

It's hard to offer more specific suggestions because you haven't said what's wrong. Yes, you say you can't boot, but you've provided *no details!* When you select the Windows entry in GRUB, what happens? Do you see a Windows logo appear but the desktop never appears? Do you see a "file not found" type error? Does the computer reboot? Does it catch on fire? Knowing precisely what the computer does when you select that option is necessary to offer anything but shot-in-the-dark solutions.

My own shot-in-the-dark suggestion is to try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) *If* the problem is with the GRUB configuration, rEFInd may work, since rEFInd uses entirely different configuration files. OTOH, if the problem is with the Windows boot loader, rEFInd won't help at all, since both GRUB and rEFInd launch Windows by using the Windows boot loader. Note that you can try rEFInd by installing it to a USB flash drive or CD-R; ready-made images for both media are available on the rEFInd downloads page.

Another comment: If you haven't done so, you must disable the Fast Startup and Hibernation features in Windows, as described [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) Of course, you can't do this if you can't boot Windows. The trouble with these features is that they cause filesystem corruption in dual-boot scenarios, and on occasion this corruption causes damage to the boot loaders. If this is the source of your problems, running `dosfsck` on the ESP (`/dev/sda1` in your case) *may* work around the problem on a one-time basis; however, if you do a `sudo dosfsck /dev/sda1` and can then boot Windows, be sure to disable those two features immediately to prevent a recurrence.

One more point: Your ESP uses FAT16. This is a minor technical violation of the EFI specification. It usually works OK like that, but some computers flake out a bit with FAT16 ESPs. There's a small chance that this is the source of your problem. If so, backing up the ESP in Ubuntu (a file-level tool like `cp`, `tar`, or `zip` will be fine), unmounting the ESP, creating a fresh FAT32 filesystem on it, re-mounting it (and adjusting `/etc/fstab`), and restoring the backup may get things working.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions and comments! I have performed most of what you have mentioned (one exception is that I cannot boot Windows even after `dosfsck`, so I couldn't turn off hibernation and fast-startup), but still couldn't get the issue fixed. I have already updated the question, so you could also see if there is anything else that I could try. No matter how it finally will turn out, I am really appreciative of your attempt to help me!

Comment: The error messages from rEFInd are consistent with either filesystem damage or an EFI with a flaky FAT driver. Your ESP (`/dev/sda1` on your system) is precisely 512 MiB in size, which is normally big enough for a FAT32 filesystem; however, it's conceivable that your firmware wants something a bit bigger. I'd first try with rEFInd and your FAT32 ESP, and if that doesn't work, as a test, convert `/dev/sda3` to a FAT32 ESP, put the files there, and try booting Windows that way. If it works, you can move and resize partitions as necessary.

Comment: @RuijieYu Have you solve the problem yet? I cannot boot my Win10-installer-image with GRUB2, it (also) says "unkown error" after confirming to "boot from CD/DVD". I can't change the boot order because of a BIOS-lock.

Comment: I have solved my Problem, `dd` does not work with Windows 10, One needs to format the USB-drive with FAT32 and copy all files of the iso onto the USB-drive.